# Async function not getting hoisted in Babel 6

Tags: babeljs

Trying to compile this piece of code in Babel 6

```
function A() {
    return async function B() {
        some.thing = C;
        async function C() {}
    }
}
```

The `async function C` is supposed to be hoisted up, right? And it does on [babel's online repl site](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=true&spec=false&code=function%20A%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20async%20function%20B%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20some.thing%20%3D%20C%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20async%20function%20C%28%29%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A):

```
...
C = function C() {
    ...
};
some.thing = C;
...
```

But on my system it compiles differently (and incorrectly):

```
...
some.thing = C;
C = (function () {
    var ref = _asyncToGenerator(regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee() {
...
```

Here `C` is defined as a variable and not getting hoisted, which results in `some.thing` undefined

[complete code gist](https://gist.github.com/laggingreflex/243af879a7f97aa2fca3)

Why this difference on my system? I'm using Babel 6.3 with `presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Babel 6. The issue is tracked in https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T6760